# Explicit elliptic fibration for $x_0^4+x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4=0$ (Fermat's quartic)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, k3-surfaces

In Huybrecht's *Lectures on K3 surfaces*, there's an explicit description of an elliptic fibration for the K3 surface $X:=\{(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3)\in\Bbb{P}_\Bbb{C}^3\mid x_0^4+x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4=0\}$ (Fermat quartic), with the following explanation (example 3.11):

[image]

I don't get how proposition 3.10 helps us. My questions are:

1. How does the existence of the elliptic curve $E$ such that $mE\in|L|$ for some $m$ allow us to conclude that there is an elliptic fibration on $X$?
2. Was the map $X\to\Bbb{P}^1$ somehow suggested by the proposition?
3. How do I verify that the map is an elliptic fibration?

Comment: The proposition isn't really *helping* here. He's just observing that you can work out this particular case of the proposition by hand. 1) The existence of an elliptic curve moving in a linear system means that there is an elliptic curve in the same linear system passing through a general point of $X$, which implies the existence of a rational map to the base. 3) He's told you; the hyperplane sections are all the union of $\ell$ with a plane cubic. Those plane cubics, which are elliptic curves generically, are the fibers.

Comment: @TabesBridges, I can't see how the fibers of $X\to\Bbb{P}^1$ are contained in a hyperplane section containing $\ell$. In order for that to be the case, it seems to me that the map should look like $\pi:(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3)\mapsto (x_1-\xi x_0:x_3-\xi x_2)$

Comment: The way I wrote it, the fiber $\pi^{-1}(a:b)$ would be contained in the hyperplane $a(x_3-\xi x_2)-b(x_1-\xi x_0)=0$ (which in particular contains $\ell$)